# How can I email links work on the front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, nodemailer

I have built some functionality into my API that sends a verification email to a user and then when a get request is made to the route the user then becomes active and can be used to login. In order to make this work on the front end I have used a res.redirect which takes me to the login page.

The problem, however, is that this means that when I want to replicate this journey in postman I then receive a load of html rather than a formatted json response. So my question is, is there a way that we can handle this request so that, depending on where it is called, a different response is sent back? As I do not think an event listener will work in the case of an email.

For context, my application uses nodejs, mongodb and pug templates.

```
`exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.params;
  const { email } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user || !((await user.signUpId) === token)) {
    return next(new AppError('Invalid link', 401));
  }

  user.ready = true;
  user.singUpId = undefined;

  await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/me`;
  await new Email(user, url).sendWelcome();

  await res.redirect('http://localhost:5000/login');
});`
```